# sql using aliases

Tags: sql, database

I seem to be having some trouble grasping the concept of using AS to create an alias, and then using that alias later.  Here is an example of a very simple query that I get an error when I run:

```
SELECT IP,  
       (SELECT server_ip as IP  
          FROM table1  
         WHERE start_time BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate  
      Group By server_ip)X  
Group By IP
```

I would expect this to just return the results from the second select statement in the server_ip column.  However I get an error messages saying IP is not an invalid column name.  Can someone explain to me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IP,
    (
    SELECT server_ip as IP
    FROM table1
    WHERE start_time BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    Group By server_ip
    )X
/*FROM WHERE ? <--------------- */
Group By IP
```

Your `SELECT` statement at the moment is

```
SELECT IP, X
GROUP BY IP
```

You need a FROM clause. `X` is a non correlated sub query at the moment. I suspect that you wanted to treat it as a derived table but even then the query makes no sense. There is no need to perform the same `GROUP BY` action twice.

Dependant upon your RDBMS you might also be able to use Common Table Expressions. Here's a somewhat contrived example of their use.

```
;WITH X AS
(
    SELECT server_ip as IP
    FROM table1
    WHERE start_time BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
),
Y AS
(
    SELECT IP
    FROM X
    Group By IP
)
SELECT IP
FROM Y
```

Comment: @MilqueToasted - Are you on SQL Server 2005+? If so check out common table expressions as well.

Comment: Oracle 9i+ (and PostgreSQL 8.4+) supports WITH, along with DB2 and Firebird (dunno versions).

Comment: @OMG - Any idea which of those materialise the results?

Comment: [Oracle 10g, according to AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:649529000346677493).

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the FROM clause:

```
  SELECT x.ip
    FROM (SELECT server_ip as IP  
            FROM table1  
           WHERE start_time BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate  
        GROUP BY server_ip) AS x 
GROUP BY x.ip
```

As is, you only need to use:

```
  SELECT server_ip as IP  
    FROM table1  
   WHERE start_time BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate  
GROUP BY server_ip
```

Comment: oh boy do I feel silly..missing the FROM.  I realize the second select is unnecessary but I was having trouble with aliases and more complex queries so I decided to make it as simple as possible and build up.  Thanks for the help all :)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT avoids the need to GROUP BY.  We have fixed his query...someone else will have to help him with aliases.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `AS` keyword befor your new name for assigning a alias to a temp table or column or etc.